# i have an issue in javascripts

Tags: javascript, html

**hi** i'am stil learning the basics in javascript i tried the flowing example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
           function name(){
                alert('ffff')
           }
     </script>

   <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" onclick="name()" />
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run it nothing happned, i tried other event such ondblclick onmouseup ... but nothing also i have tried this in many browser but stil nothing .. did i do something wrong ? thanks and sorry for bad english

Comment: javascript in modern browsers is fairly picky sometimes (ie not all the time) so you don't have a `;` after your alert so try that and see if it works.

Comment: Look here before you ask. http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: @Mardzis — Why? It doesn't explain this problem and is generally awful.

Comment: @Quentin Becasue it is hyper trivial problem.

Comment: @Mardzis — This isn't a hyper trivial problem. It's a very obscure naming conflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are meeting a weird scoping interaction that occurs when you use intrinsic event attributes.

When you call `name()`, the scoping rules find the `name` *property* of the input element before they find the global `name` variable holding your function. The `name` property holds a string or is undefined (so you get an error when you try to treat it as a function).

Don't use intrinsic event attributes. Bind your event handlers using JavaScript.

```js
function name(event) {
    alert('ffff');
}

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', name);
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: You should always give your inputs an ID and name attribute. If there were more than one input your solution would add this to every text input on the page. Adding an EventListener is overkill unless you are applying it to a great number of elemenets, and not just one. Just change the name of the function as skobaljic suggested.

Comment: @DavidP — `querySelector` returns the first element that matches the selector. It doesn't return the document object and provide a custom `addEventListener` method that does event delegation with checking on the selector. And you *have* to add an event listener if you want to do something on an event - doing it with JavaScript is a much cleaner approach than  `onclick` attributes.

Comment: I have asked that my answer be deleted, even though using a semi-colon is good practice and did not deserve all the down votes. Still believe adding an EventListener via javascript is stupid if you are only adding for 1 element.

Comment: @DavidP — If you want to comment about good practice then *comment* about it, don't give answers that don't solve the problem: they attract downvotes. As mentioned, you have to have an event listener if you want to listen for an event. Binding event listeners with JavaScript instead of HTML attributes is [best](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup) [practise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_JavaScript) (and, as a bonus, the scoping rules when you do it in JS instead of HTML are much clearer).

Comment: Ok - I will admit to my error on semi-colons if you can admit to the fact that you have left out a "name" and "id" attributes on the input. That is definitely not good practice.

Comment: @DavidP — They weren't in the original code, they aren't required to solve the problem being asked about, if I were to write a best practises guide on how to identify elements in different circumstances I'd be here all day.